# .htaccess rewrite folder exception

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?grandparent=$1&parent=$2&page=$3
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?&parent=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

But I need this to not pass to the index page for some sub-domains, so I have the following rewrite conditions before this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/.*$
```

So that the rules will not apply when looking for any file in those directories (including files that may be in sub-directories of those directories). Yet they still keep getting rewritten to `index.php`.

How can I make exceptions for these directories?

Answer (score 7):

Your RewriteCond should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin|js|css)/ [NC]
```

Additionally you must use `L` and `QSA` flags in all the RewriteRule lines like this:

```
# skip these paths for redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin|js|css)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?grandparent=$1&parent=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?&parent=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This worked for me but surprisingly without exclamation mark like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin|js|css)/ [NC]`. I'm not an htaccess mod-rewrite expert but maybe it should be edited?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin|css|js)/
RewriteRule . - [S=3] #skip the next 3 rules if the RewriteCond match

RewriteRule ([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?&parent=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?grandparent=$1&parent=$2&page=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```